# Who's calendar reminder is in control?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

When I send a calendar appointment using Outlook 10 to my boss and set the reminder to NONE, does the reminder stay at NONE on my boss's calendar or does it change to my boss's default reminder setting on her calendar? (she uses a default reminder of 15 minutes)  Will her calendar appointment reminder her at 15 minutes til or NONE?

Comment: What happens when you create an appointment, set the reminder to none, send it to your boss, and ask her how it appears? My assumption is her Outlook follows her default reminder settings for appointments sent from others, otherwise you'd have jokers sending you appointments with reminders 20 days in advance.

Comment: In my experience, it takes the reminder of the owner of the appointment.

Answer (score 9):

I did a round of testing with this one today actually, Outlook 2010 clients and Exchange 2010 SP1.

It seems that the reminder time set by the meeting organiser is inherited by the attendee *unless* the organiser set it to None. In that case the attendee's Outlook seems to see it almost as a null value and adds a reminder with the attendee's default reminder time (File > Options > Calendar > Default Reminders).

Of course the attendee can always override the reminder time, but if they don't, that's what seems to happen. I thought it was weird enough to post =)

Comment: Five years after your answer, in Outlook 2013, either I'm doing something completely wrong or your answer seems to be false -- https://superuser.com/q/1234143/156554

Answer (score 2):

The reminder would show up as NONE on your boss's calendar. By default, [Outlook appointment reminders](http://blog.mcstech.net/index.php/training/outlook-microsoft-training/outlook-setting-reminders-when-inviting-others-to-appointments/) take the value set by the creator of the invite, not the attendee's preferences.

Once the attendee accepts the invite, he/she can always double-click the invite and change the reminder time.
[image]

In case you think your boss won't pay attention to the reminder time, it's best you set it to a value other than NONE.

Answer (score 0):

When I send a calendar appointment from my home email to my office email (or vice versa) via Outlook 2010 (both places), the invitee's reminder changes from the 1 day default at both places to 15 minutes.